toast not showing on Android U
I have a background service which calls Toast.show() (from Kotlin) which works perfectly fine on Android-S, but the exact same code fails on Android-U. Here's the simple code snippet:
 fun showAlertMessage(sText: String) {
       val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

        handler.post {
            val toast = Toast.makeText(this, sText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
            toast.show()
        }
    }

Any ideas what's changed on U?
Thanks

https://medium.com/@debuggingisfun/toasting-from-android-13-b3c45877ec1e

Try updating your method to use applicationContext for a more robust approach:
fun showAlertMessage(context: Context, sText: String) {
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.post {
        val toast = Toast.makeText(context.applicationContext, sText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
        toast.show()
    }
}


Thanks for your comments, I found a solution here, https://github.com/termux/termux-app/tree/master need to create a TextView and use that within toast, works like a charm
